# Search by One-to-Many Association values without limiting the remaining values

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql, query-builder

### Background

My client wishes to have a Product catalogue built with many different kinds of attributes depending on the Category. The client also wishes to have quite a comprehensive search ability that checks over Product names and their attributes. The desired display format is grouped by Category and then a table of Products that are matched to the search term.

### Condensed Entity Overview

```
Category
    - name (string)
    - products (1-to-Many:Product)
    - attributes (1-to-Many:Attribute)
Attribute
    - name (string)
    - isDropdown (bool) - flag meaning can either be custom or from the dropdown options
    - attributeOptions (1-to-Many:AttributeOption)
AttributeOption
    - attribute (Many-to-1:Attribute)
    - value
ProductAttributeValue
    - attribute (Many-to-1:Attribute)
    - selectedOption (Many-to-1:AttributeOption)
    - value (string)
Product
    - name (string)
    - attributeValues (1-to-Many:ProductAttributeValue)
    - category (Many-to-1:Category)
```

### The issue

Searching by Product name is easy enough:

```
$search = 'gloves and stuff';
$searchTerms = explode(' ', $search);

$categoriesWithProducts = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('c, p, a, av, ao')
    ->from('AcmeBundle:Category', 'c')
    ->innerJoin('c.products', 'p')
    ->leftJoin('c.attributes', 'a')
    ->leftJoin('p.attributeValues', 'av')
    ->leftJoin('av.selectedOption', 'ao')
;
$i = 0;
foreach ($searchTerm as $st) {
    $categoriesWithProducts
        ->orWhere('p.name LIKE ?'.$i)
        ->setParameter($i++, '%' . $st . '%')
    ;
}
$categoriesWithProducts = $categoriesWithProducts->getQuery()->getResult();
```

And output is achieved with this Twig code:

```
{% for category in categoriesWithProducts %}
<h2>{{ category.name }}</h2>
<table>
    <thead>
        {% for attribute in category.attributes %}
            <th>{{ attribute.name }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for product in category.products %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
                {% for product in category.attributes %}
                    <td>
                    {% for attributeValue in product.attributeValues if attributeValue.attribute == attribute %}
                    {{ attribute.isDropdown ? attributeValue.selectedOption.value : attributeValue.value }}
                    {% endfor %}
                    </td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
{% endfor %}
```

Resulting output:

[image: Screenshot 1]

However when I modify the query to also match attributes from the search terms:

```
$categoriesWithProducts = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('c, p, a, av, ao')
    ->from('AcmeBundle:Category', 'c')
    ->innerJoin('c.products', 'p')
    ->leftJoin('c.attributes', 'a')
    ->leftJoin('p.attributeValues', 'av')
    ->leftJoin('av.selectedOption', 'ao')
;
$i = 0;
foreach ($searchTerm as $st) {
    $categoriesWithProducts
        ->orWhere('p.name LIKE ?'.$i)
        ->orWhere('av.value LIKE ?'.$i)
        ->orWhere('ao.value LIKE ?'.$i)
        ->setParameter($i++, '%' . $st . '%')
    ;
}
```

The search will still work for matched Product names, **but** produce subsets of `attributeValues` and `selectedOption` when matches are found from the `$search` term. For example, with `$search = 'red'`:

[image: Screenshot 2]

And `$search = 'red small'`:

[image: Screenshot 3]

### My attempt to fix

I tried using two joins for both of the associated entities, but ended up getting duplicates in my result set which produces double output in my Twig render.

Code:

```
$categoriesWithProducts = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('c, p, a, av, ao, avSearch, aoSearch')
    ->from('AcmeBundle:Category', 'c')
    ->innerJoin('c.products', 'p')
    ->leftJoin('c.attributes', 'a')
    ->leftJoin('p.attributeValues', 'av')
    ->leftJoin('av.selectedOption', 'ao')
    ->leftJoin('p.attributeValues', 'avSearch')
    ->leftJoin('av.selectedOption', 'aoSearch')
;
$i = 0;
foreach ($searchTerm as $st) {
    $categoriesWithProducts
        ->orWhere('p.name LIKE ?'.$i)
        ->orWhere('avSearch.value LIKE ?'.$i)
        ->orWhere('aoSearch.value LIKE ?'.$i)
        ->setParameter($i++, '%' . $st . '%')
    ;
}
```

Result with `$search = 'gloves and stuff'`:

[image: Screenshot 4]

And with `$search = 'red small'` (note the duplicate `Red` and `Small` entries but singular results for the other attributes):

[image: Screenshot 5]

I've tried various ways to hide the `aoSearch` and `avSearch` results:

1. Aliasing them as `HIDDEN aoSearch` and `HIDDEN avSearch` does nothing
2. Removing `aoSearch` and `avSearch` from the `SELECT` reverts back to the broken subset issue found in the 2nd and 3rd screenshots.

### Question

I wish to get all of the attributes for a product shown in the table if a match is found among any of the Product's attributes. **Is there a way I can hide the matches from `aoSearch` and `avSearch` that I've missed?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only half an hour after posting this question and I have a workaround:

The only way I've figured out a solution so far is by using the `EXISTS` function within a single `orWhere` clause so the match is contained within the subquery:

```
$categoriesWithProducts = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('c, p, a, av, ao')
    ->from('AcmeBundle:Category', 'c')
    ->innerJoin('c.products', 'p')
    ->leftJoin('c.attributes', 'a')
    ->leftJoin('p.attributeValues', 'av')
    ->leftJoin('av.selectedOption', 'ao')
;
$i = 0;
$subQuery = '';
foreach ($searchTerm as $st) {
    if ($i > 0) $subQuery .= ' OR ';
    $subQuery = 'sao.text LIKE ?'.$i.' OR pav.text LIKE ?'.$i;
    $categoriesWithProducts
        ->orWhere('p.name LIKE ?'.$i)
        ->setParameter($i++, '%' . $st . '%')
    ;
}
$categoriesWithProducts->orWhere(
    'EXISTS (
        SELECT pav 
        FROM AcmeBundle:ProductAttributeValue pav
        LEFT JOIN pav.selectedOption sao
        WHERE pav.product = p AND ('.$subQuery.'))
    ');
$categoriesWithProducts = $categoriesWithProducts->getQuery()->getResult();
```

This gives me perfect search results with attributes galore!